# SSAS MDX Calculated Members's equivalent in Tabular model

Tags: ssas, dax, tabular

I am new in SSAS tabular and need your help.
Is it possible and how to write the following MDX statement in DAX :

```
 CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures][Duration none justified]
 AS ([Event][EVT]&[xyz],[Measures][Duration event]),
 FORMAT_STRING = "#" ,
 NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR = { [Measures][Duration event] },
 VISIBLE = 1
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Hello Everyone!! This is old topic but i still looking the answer of my question :    
    CREATE
                MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[event]
                AS ([Event TAG].[CODE VT].&[AS],[Measures].[Duration event TAG])
    ,
                FORMAT_STRING = "#" ,
                NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR = { [Measures].[Duration event TAG] },
                VISIBLE = 1;  

How to write this statement in DAX in SSAS tabular .thank you for you help

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
Duration none justified = var __input = calculate(sum([Duration event])
, filter(ALL('Event'[EVT]), 'Event'[EVT] = "xyz")
)

return
if(ISBLANK([Duration event]), BLANK(), __input)
```

Comment: Hello, thansk for your answer. but it is not working for me. I am in visual studio 2017 and want to write the statement as measure . It throw error when i use variable but i have wrong result when i just use : 

Try this solution:

Duration none justified:= calculate(sum([Duration event])
, filter(ALL('Event'[EVT]), 'Event'[EVT] = "xyz")
) . just notice that [Duration event] is another calculated measure , sometimes i can see it but sometimes i cannot , how can I use calculated measure in a another calculated measure ? thank you and sorry ..This is my first tabular project

Comment: Provide an error message.
variables are available in SSAS Tabular 2016 (and newest).
Probably you can just omit parentheses and sum function.

calculate([Duration event] , filter(ALL('Event'[EVT]), 'Event'[EVT] = "xyz") )

We can use measure in a measure just typing its name like above (but not as a filter condition -> here we must use variables like in my answer).

Comment: See below error message : Échec de l'enregistrement des modifications sur le serveur. Erreur retournée : « A circular dependency was detected: Measure: 'FactEvenementGTA'[Duration none justified], Measure: 'FactEvenementGTA'[Duration none justified].
 ».

Comment: Hello Everyone!! This is old topic but i still looking the answer of my question :    
    CREATE
                MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[event]
                AS ([Event TAG].[CODE VT].&[AS],[Measures].[Duration event TAG])
    ,
                FORMAT_STRING = "#" ,
                NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR = { [Measures].[Duration event TAG] },
                VISIBLE = 1;  

How to write this statement in DAX in SSAS tabular .thank you for you help

Comment: maybe this can help you:

https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/converting-mdx-to-dax-first-steps/